# Codeigniter- cache view into a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, view

i'm wondering if it's possible to cache a view which is loaded inside another view.

I do:

view.php:

```
<div>
<?php echo $this->load->view('modules/new_view'); ?>
</div>
```

so view.php requires a new view inside himself, can i cache the `views/modules/new_view.php` content?

Comment: CodeIgniter output caching, caches whole of the page. It works per-page basis. If you want to cache sections on a page separately, take a look at [Caching Driver](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) and give it a try. You should do the logic in controller, return the view as string, cache the string, push the cached data to the main view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codeigniter has **[Web Page Caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html)**

> CodeIgniter lets you cache your pages in order to achieve maximum
>   performance.
>
> Although CodeIgniter is quite fast, the amount of dynamic information
>   you display in your pages will correlate directly to the server
>   resources, memory, and processing cycles utilized, which affect your
>   page load speeds. By caching your pages, since they are saved in their
>   fully rendered state, you can achieve performance that nears that of
>   static web pages.

To do it you would use the code below where `n` is the number of minutes you wish the page to remain cached between refreshes. You can place it anywhere within a function.

```
$this->output->cache(n);
```

**Update**

To cache just a portion of the page, or just a single view, you can use [**CodeIgniter-Cache**](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache).

> CodeIgniter-Cache is a partial caching library for CodeIgniter. It
>   allows you to write and get chunks of data to and from the filesystem.
>   By storing complex or large chunks of data in serialized form on the
>   file system you can relieve stress from the database or simply cache
>   Twitter calls.

**Another alternative**

[**MP Cache**](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/MP-Cache%3a-Simple-flexible-Caching-of-parts-of-code): Simple flexible Caching of parts of code

Comment: if i put output cache to a view inside a parent view the cache will affect also the parent view