# Does Codeigniter allow caching a particular view instead of whole webpage?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, caching

I wanted to understand `Codeigniter's Caching`. I enabled caching for my application and it started to cache my webpage.But my problem is it caches the whole page instead of a view.

I mean I have a layout where I load multiple views. Like Left Sidebar and Right Sidebar. Now  I want to cache only these as they would be common for all user accounts. So I can show cached view for other users. But Codeigniter caches the whole page and therefore when some other user logs in, the information is showed for last loggedin user or some other user.

I tried to cache in my Left and Right sidebar using this:

```
$this->output->cache($n);
```

So is it possible to cache only some part of my webpage, or a particular view?
Or I need to apply some logic, so when different users login they don't see any one else's account information.

I refereed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192259/codeigniter-cache-view-into-a-view) But I did not understood so posting again.

Answer (score 1):

I havent used CI Caching before so have copied the example from the guide - but note the 3rd parameter of the loading view. It enables you to return output. Assuming that you create your view - use true as the third part and then just that specific element can be cached by CI.

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo'))
{
    echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
    $foo = $this->load->view('your_view',$params,true);

    // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
    $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 300);
}

echo $foo;
```